# C# Selenium keeps creating chrome instances

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My question is, how to prevent Selenium from creating multiple chrome instances?

Details:

Using Selenium and chromedriver I created an automation testing program. Strangely, although most runs are as expected, about one out of twenty would create many chrome console (black, empty) windows, with one actual browser window. The browser window would finish the work but not disposed correctly, and no exceptions were thrown. Once I manually closed the only browser window, all other windows were closed too.

This time I caught it in visual studio debug mode, I found even my program paused at a breakpoint, the chrome console windows were still being spawned. In the task manager there were 17 chrome.exe sessions, and no chrome was created before my program started.

Out of all the console windows, only one (the leftmost one on screen, maybe the first one that was created) had some information and all others were blank:

> [2400:1204:0412/171721.457:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver
> message (Error) eglCreateContext: Requested GLES version (3.0) is
> greater than max supported (2, 0).
> [2400:1204:0412/171721.578:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(352)]
> eglCreateContext failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

Then after the only browser window finished routine work, another spawned console window contained some additional information:

> [8016:13204:0412/172631.461:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to
> move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
> [8016:13204:0412/172631.462:ERROR:cache_util.cc(146)] Unable to move
> cache folder
> C:\Users\cal\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2496_2059150988\Default\Cache\Cache_Data
> to
> C:\Users\cal\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2496_2059150988\Default\Cache\old_Cache_Data_000
> [8016:13204:0412/172631.463:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(186)] Unable to create
> cache

Below is my c# code for creating chrome browser:

```
    public static ChromeDriver GetChromeBrowser(bool bHeadless = false, string sProxy = "", string chromeProfileDir = "")
    {

        var chromeoptions = GetChromeOptions(bHeadless, chromeProfileDir);

        var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

        // hide prompt window
        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        ChromeDriver browser = null;
        int nCount = 0;
        while (browser == null && nCount < 3)
        {
            try
            {
                browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeoptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // try a different port:                
                chromeoptions = GetChromeOptions(bHeadless, chromeProfileDir);
            }
            nCount++;
        }

        return browser;
    }

    private static ChromeOptions GetChromeOptions(bool bHeadless = false, string chromeProfileDir = "")
    {
        var chromeoptions = new ChromeOptions();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chromeProfileDir))
        {
            string sProfileFullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), chromeProfileDir);
            if (!Directory.Exists(sProfileFullPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(sProfileFullPath);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    
                }
            }
            chromeoptions.AddArguments("--profile-directory=" + sProfileFullPath);
        }

        chromeoptions.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");

        chromeoptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");

        chromeoptions.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeoptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Dismiss;

        int nPortNumber = GetARandomPortNumber();

        chromeoptions.AddArguments($"--remote-debugging-port={nPortNumber.ToString()}");

        if (bHeadless)
        {
            chromeoptions.AddArguments("--headless");
            chromeoptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");

            // do not load images:
            chromeoptions.AddArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
        }

        return chromeoptions;
    }
```

I have also made a screenshot to show how it look like. As you can see, many blank chrome windows were created.
[image]

The problem is highly intermittent and hard to reproduce. I don't know if it is enough to pinpoint the problem. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot many questions. Can you summarize which one issue you would like to address in this discussion?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium The question is how to prevent Selenium from creating many instances? I added a lot of things only trying to provide as much detail as I can to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Which version of ChromeDriver are you running? Which version of Chrome are you running? The major versions need to match, or all kinds of weird things can happen.